# Content aligned with a figure changes positions when the figure is uncovered (beamer)

Tags: beamer, alignment, adjustbox

When I align two minipages together, the contents location changes after a figure in one `minipage` is uncovered. The distance from the rule to the upper palettes illustrates this

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, symbolre, symbolmisc]{mathastext}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\MTDeclareVersion[it]{charter}{T1}{bch}{m}{n}

\MTversion*{charter}


% END_FOLD


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \uncover<+->{$\vphantom{1}$}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}

    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.45\textwidth}, valign=t}

        \includegraphics<+->[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}

    \end{adjustbox}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.45\textwidth}, valign=t}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> Modeling the addition of branch $Z_{b}$ between two existing buses \mbox{($k$ and $p$)} in Brown's method
        \end{itemize}

    \end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably using `\visible` for that is a simpler option.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, symbolre, symbolmisc]{mathastext}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\MTDeclareVersion[it]{charter}{T1}{bch}{m}{n}

\MTversion*{charter}


% END_FOLD


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \uncover<+->{$\vphantom{1}$}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}

    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.45\textwidth}, valign=t}

        \visible<+->{\includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,
        width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}

    \end{adjustbox}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.45\textwidth}, valign=t}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> Modeling the addition of branch $Z_{b}$ between two existing buses \mbox{($k$ and $p$)} in Brown's method
        \end{itemize}

    \end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know that. When I typed `\includegraphics`, I discovered that it has its own overlay entries. But the skill of using phantom contents is still worth noting and learning

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Yes, it is definitely but I am not sure I would use it here. Of course, you are the OP who asked the question. If you feel that your phantom trick is the way to go, this is your choice.

Comment: That was the only thing I could have thought of by the time I was troubleshooting, but why does not it work to uncover the image with the overlay specifications of `\includegraphics` ?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I do not now what you mean by "not work". At least the above does work.

Comment: The original question uses the overlay specifications of `\includegraphics` to uncover the image, but with this solution, the position of text contents change. This is what I mean by saying what I said. As a result, you wrote that we must use `\visible` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a vertical phantom of **exactly** the same figure; that is, place another figure with the original one and use `phantom=v`, with `adjustbox`. This will not typeset anything, but it will force tell LaTeX to make a vertical space equal to the one that the figure would have occupied if it was typeset. The syntax is

```
\adjustbox{phantom=v}{\includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, symbolre, symbolmisc]{mathastext}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\MTDeclareVersion[it]{charter}{T1}{bch}{m}{n}

\MTversion*{charter}


% END_FOLD


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \uncover<+->{$\vphantom{1}$}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}

    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.45\textwidth}, valign=t}

        \includegraphics<+->[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}% do not remove this
        \adjustbox{phantom=v}{\includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}

    \end{adjustbox}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.45\textwidth}, valign=t}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> Modeling the addition of branch $Z_{b}$ between two existing buses \mbox{($k$ and $p$)} in Brown's method
        \end{itemize}

    \end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```